# How ro map pageup/pagedown in secure crt as it works in normal putty?

Tags: mapping

I'm using securecrt and I'm having problem with the pageup/down keys as they are not functional. How to map them so that they behave as in putty?

I referred to some sites and tried with the following methods but of no use.

PageUp – \033[5~
PageDown – \033[6~

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Srikanth

Comment: anyone has info on this?

Answer (score 0):

It think that mapping actually works.
The problem is in the program you are using.
For me less did not listen to the page up/page down but nano worked just as expected.
I think that for less you have to add some mapping on the target machine itself.
Check out this link (I have not tested this):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/why-dont-page-u-down-home-end-work-in-less-on-solaris-over-ssh-from-ubuntu